# htaccess white list not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an `.htaccess` rule for whitelist like this:

```
# Allow whitelisted files
<FilesMatch "^(index.php|imgsize.php|routing.php|browse.php|css.php|joiner.php|js_localize.php|upload.php | watermark.php)*$">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
deny from 192.168.1.255</FilesMatch>
```

`watermark.php` does not work properly.

What is the problem?

Comment: That code as shown makes no sense, it should only produce an error. Is this part of a `Files`/`FilesMatch` directive, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the space before watermark.php and it should work...i edited your code as follow:

```
(index.php|imgsize.php|routing.php|browse.php|css.php|joiner.php|js_localize.php|upload.php|watermark.php)*$
```